# Error while Installing APK Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

I am unable to run application on any android phone. I have Android Studio 3.3 , and it used to work fine. And now suddnely it shows ***Error while Installing APK . Session 'app': Error Installing APK*** 
I tried :

-- Clean, Build , 
-- Invalidate caches and Restart ,
-- Disabled Instant Run ,
-- Checked devices for storage , USB debugging

Nothing works. I cannot install the apk on android device.

Any one knows how to resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue before, & turns out the device just had insufficient memory for the app.
Try free up some memory on your device.

Comment: Maybe you could complete your answer by explaining to OP (or any interested reader) how to free up memory

Comment: @Gio No it doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems too broad to give an appropriately specific answer. I can give some recommendations that you might have not done yet.

1. Remove app from device and install it again.
2. Maybe you have not allowed USB debugging in developer options.
3. Maybe you have not allowed USB debugging on this phone. The dialog that appears whenever you connect the phone to the pc.

Also, I would suggest adding a screenshot of the error

Comment: As i said, it was working earlier. I have updated the question with picture and you can see i have just opened a new application.

Comment: Can you install app on the emulator?

Comment: No . Its the same even on emulator.

Comment: Try to isolate the part that causes problem. 1 sync gradle files. 2 build app 3 generate apk. If nobe of these give errors than it is deployment problem, which means either usb cable is malfunctioning or adb is having some trouble. If it is adb, kill the process from task manager and restart android studio.

Comment: i have also tried to kill and start adb again. no help there!

Comment: If killing adb process from task manager didn't help then I suggest to restart your computer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187282/discussion-between-ravi-and-nkhar).